# Turning this code into a python function

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
name1 = input(userQuestions[0]).lower()
while name1 == "" or not name1.replace(' ','').isalpha():
    name1 = input(userQuestions[0]).lower()
```

The 'userQuestions[ ]' are:

```
userQuestions = (
    "Give me name 1?\n",
    "Give me name 2?\n",
    "Give me name 3?\n",
    )
```

To use my validation on all 3 questions, how do I put this into a function to make it more efficient instead of repeating a similar statement x3?
The only thing that should change in the function is the name (eg. 'name1' to 'name2', 'name3'), and the userQuestions[ ] (eg. userQuestions[0], ...[1], ...[2]).

Comment: Read the doc: [Python lists](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm), [Python functions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com//python/python_functions.htm)

Comment: I know there are resources out there but I have looked everywhere for something that is specific to my problem. - making the above mentioned values change on every question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly then I think this is what you are looking for. This loops through your `userQuestions` tuple and calls the function `get_user()` which returns the new username and adds it to the list `users`

```
def get_user(userQuestion):
    name1 = input(userQuestion).lower()
    while name1 == "" or not name1.replace(' ','').isalpha():
        name1 = input(userQuestion).lower()
    return name1

userQuestions = (
    "Give me name 1?\n",
    "Give me name 2?\n",
    "Give me name 3?\n",
    )
users = []

for i in userQuestions:
    users.append(get_user(i))

print(users)
```

You could change this up a little since the only thing you are changing in the questions is the number you could put the string in the function and only pass the number in like so,

```
def get_user(x):
    name1 = input('Give me name ' + x + '\n').lower()
    while name1 == "" or not name1.replace(' ','').isalpha():
        name1 = input('Give me name ' + x + '\n').lower()
    return name1

users = []

for i in range(3):
    users.append(get_user(str(i+1)))

print(users)
```

This way it is easier to scale to any number of users. Say if you have 20 users all you have to do is change the range to 20 instead of adding 17 more lines to you `userQuestions` tuple.